# how can i make docker image smaller then now

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

i try to build my node api then after finish the build
it's too big
my real node api volume is 39mb but docker image is almost 1gb
i wanna make smaller how can i do that

this is my docker file

```
FROM node:carbon-slim

# Create app directory
WORKDIR C:\Users\YSJ\Desktop\SJ\node\node-start

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install


# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]


$ docker history 3b82023a6f85
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
3b82023a6f85        51 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["npm" "start"]          0B
14f01df0872f        51 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080                  0B
f9544ca80948        52 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:22b1ef58b9b5b2cd6…   32.8MB
3cbf711ed3c1        56 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c npm install                          40.2MB
3a54a59c0618        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY multi:89514c7faadf5d8…   91.8kB
8c34688e9f86        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /C:UsersYSJDesktop…   0B
52a261fa5e4b        4 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]                 0B
<missing>           4 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B
<missing>           4 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:238737301d473041…   116B
<missing>           4 days ago           /bin/sh -c set -ex   && for key in     6A010…   5.48MB
<missing>           4 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.19.1      0B
<missing>           4 days ago           /bin/sh -c ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print…   54MB
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=8.16.2      0B
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c groupadd --gid 1000 node   && use…   333kB
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   562MB
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   142MB
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   7.81MB
<missing>           5 days ago           /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   23.2MB
<missing>           6 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           6 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:fdf0128645db4c8b9…   101MB
```

Comment: You might be able to try the carbon-slim [base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) instead of carbon.  carbon-slim doesn't include many extra packages, but its likely still too big for you at [52 MB](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/node/remote/carbon-slim.md) (compressed transfer size).

Comment: @robsiemb it's not work wat i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the Node Docker image size grows due to node_modules and you can not reduce the size as these are the requirement of application but here are few suggestions that will reduce the size of image.

use `node:alpine` you will save **60MB**.

[image]

> Second thing if you are running the image in production or also in
>   staging if dev packages not required you can use `--production` flag.
>
> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies in package.json.
>
> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable
>   is set to production), **npm will not install modules listed in
>   devDependencies**.

[npm install for production](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

So if you build for production then

```
RUN npm install --production
```

Also better to keep the docker build context as small as possible as you can. There should be only Dockerfile and code.

```
COPY . .
```

This will copy everything from the current directory. Better to place host node_modules in .dockerignore.

Create file `.dockerignore` in your docker build context directory

```
node_modules
```

Add anything that you do not want in the image. as `npm install` will install node modules in the image.